# Infinite-scroll issue with MySQL random function?

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, masonry

I'm using [jQuery infinite-scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) plugin on a masonry gallery. My question is duplicate records load in Infinite Scroll when sorting by Random `ORDER BY rand()`.

Ex: If I have added 10 images to database,

- loading home page   - *1* , **5** , *3* , *4* , **2** ( *five images loaded randomly* )
- loading second page  - *6* , **2** , *9* , *8* , **5** ( *2 and 5 have loaded again* )
- Reached the END without 7 and 10

index.php:

```
<?php

include ("includes/db.php");
$per_page = 5;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {

    $page = $_GET["page"];
}
else {
    $page=1;
}

$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

$query = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
$result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);
?>


<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<div id ="container" class="transitions-enabled infinite-scroll clearfix">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>

        <?php } ?>

    <nav id="page-nav">
        <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page ?>"></a>
    </nav>
</div> <!-- END Container -->
```

All this codes are working without any issue when sorting by DESCENDING [`ORDER BY 1 DESC`]. I think I need to add something new to this codes.

script.js:

```
$(function() {
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    gutter: 10,
    itemSelector: '.item',
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
    // infinite scroll options...
    navSelector  : "#page-nav",
    nextSelector : "#page-nav a",
    itemSelector : ".item",
    loading: {
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif',
          speed: 0,
        }
  },
    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });
    }
);

});
```

Comment: how many images are you dealing with? If  you can send all and splice array randomly in client would be fairly simple, otherwise you have to keep track of what's been sent and modify query accordingly

Comment: 18 images per page and 100+ in database.

Comment: send all image data once in json array and move the random logic to client then. Remove from array as you populate DOM...no repeats that way

Comment: Still I have a same issue. Please can you Answer to this with a little code example to check my codes? appreciate your comments @charlietfl thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pass an argument to mysql rand
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

> If a constant integer argument N is specified, it is used as the seed
>   value, which produces a repeatable sequence of column values.

like this (not tested :))

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION["rand"])) // generate random number if none 
    {
    $_SESSION["rand"] = rand();//generate random number

    }
$rand = $_SESSION["rand"];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY rand($rand) LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
```